# Angular 2 component display issue height width is null

Tags: user-interface, angular, components, selector, display

when i am using a component-selector to display a component like:

```
<app-search></app-search>
```

then the width and height of the rendered component is 0px x 0px in the developer console. So if i have following html code after this component it  gets rendered on the AppSearch Component UI. What i am doing wrong? Can anyone explain how to do it right?

Comment: Try setting its display to block

Comment: I tried. Then the width gets setted but height is still 0px... I dont know why. It should be the whole size of the component...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my problem, my `<app-search>` Component hat a wrapper div, that was set to `position:absolute`. I changed it and the component gets his normal width and height.